# Creating view with overlapping circle

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a simple `UIView` line and then a circle on top if it. i'm however not sure how i'm suppose to draw the circle without making hierarchy problems? so far i have below, which jut creates the line

**line**

```
    self.stepLine = UIView()
    self.stepLine.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stepView.addSubview(self.stepLine)

    self.stepLine.backgroundColor = Color.theme.value

    self.stepLine.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stepView.bottomAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
    self.stepLine.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 6).isActive = true
    self.stepLine.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stepView.leftAnchor).isActive = true



override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.stepLine.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width/2).isActive = true
}
```

**Illustration**

[image]

Comment: "I'm trying to create a simple UIView line and then a circle on top if it."  Draw them where?

Comment: What do you mean "hierarchy problems"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let circleView = UIView()
circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 10 // half of the width/height dimension
circleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
stepView.addSubview(circleView)

circleView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stepLine.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
circleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stepLine.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
circleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
circleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
```

Or some variation thereof. But this is the general concept I would suggest given the nature of the code you presented.